# Why Python compiler doesn't ignore syntax errors after exit()?

Tags: python, compilation, compiler-optimization

If you run a Python code and then call `exit()`, it will exit the program and the following codes won't run. But I added `exit()` to my program and after I had some syntax error and the program crashed. I want to know why the Python compiler didn't optimize my code before running it. I tried this issue with logical errors and it ignored them, like `index out of range` and so on. So why the below code doesn't work and `SyntaxError` happens?

```py
print("Hi")
exit()
if
```

Comment: Python needs to compile the entire file, you need to fix your syntax errors

Comment: why python doesn't optimize the code before compiling it?

Comment: Your code is not valid, it contains syntax errors, so there would be nothing to optimize anyway.

Comment: By "optimize" you mean "ignore everything after a call to exit()"? You could have redefined the `exit()` function in some totally arbitrary way, how would the compiler know?

Comment: I mean logically it should run because the syntax error is after the `exit()`.

Comment: It can't compile your program precisely *because* it's a compiler (to bytecode which it will later interpret).  It doesn't stop parsing when it sees an `exit()`, unlike a shell reading and interpreting a shell script one line at a time. (That's not "optimization").  Python compiles it to bytecode that calls `exit` if that point in the program is reached.

Comment: it's not an arbitrary process. `C` compiler works smarter how does the `C` compiler can detect it?

Comment: For example, if you run a `while 1` program with C it doesn't run because of logic. but why do python doesn't do the same thing?

Comment: What are you talking about?  C compilers choke on syntax errors in unreachable blocks, like `int foo(){ if(0) if if; }`  https://godbolt.org/z/vY7Psafe9.  Only `#if 0` *preprocessor* stuff, or comments, can hide stuff from the compiler so it doesn't have to be valid syntax and grammar.

Comment: @Alirezaarabi because you need to *parse the code* to optimize it, and it can't be parsed according to Python's grammer. In any case, it would be *really bad* if Python just ignored a syntax error. That isn't desirable behavior to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't compile your program precisely *because* it's a compiler (to bytecode which it will later interpret).  It doesn't stop parsing when it sees an `exit()`, unlike a shell reading and interpreting a shell script one line at a time. (That's not "optimization", BTW).

Python compiles it to bytecode that calls `exit` if that point in the program is reached.  Even unreachable code has to be *syntactically* valid so the whole file compiles.  But since it never actually executes, it can't cause any run-time errors.

> It's not an arbitrary process. C compiler works smarter how does the C compiler can detect it?
>
> For example, if you run a `while 1` program with C it doesn't run because of logic. but why do python doesn't do the same thing?

**That's not true.**

C compilers choke on syntax errors in unreachable blocks, like `int foo(){ if(0) if if; }`.  Also, `while 1` isn't valid C syntax.

https://godbolt.org/z/cP83Y866b.  Only `#if 0` *preprocessor* stuff, or comments, can hide stuff from the compiler so it doesn't have to be valid syntax and grammar.

**Syntax and grammar need to be valid in the whole file for it to parse into something to compiler can compile.**

In C and C++, unreachable code (that isn't commented out) even has to be valid in terms of types matching, e.g. `T x = y;` won't compile if `T` is `int` but `y`'s type is `char*`. That would be syntactically valid but "ill-formed". [Per cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):  *Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. `if constexpr` is not a substitute for the `#if` preprocessing directive*

But inside a template, it can, for example hide stuff.  https://godbolt.org/z/frTcbMb3T

```cpp
template <typename T>  // being a template function makes if constexpr special
void foo(int x) {
  if constexpr (false) {
      int x = "hi";    // ill-formed, type mismatch.  But still valid *syntax*
  }

#if 1           // 0 would truly ignore all text until the closing #endif
  if constexpr (false) {
//      int x = = 2;  // syntax error if uncommented
  }
#endif
}
```